# Can I submit IOS app created on non-IOS devices (like, using VMware or any other way) or without MacBook?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-application, ios14

I need to know if I can submit IOS app which is not built within apple device.

I'm using IOS in VMware to create IOS app. But now I heard that, In IOS 14 they are not allowed those app which aren't built within apple device. They are not allowing apps which are built with VMware.

Anyone know about this? Please help me. I got stuck at this point.

Please make this clear for me and many more developers who got confusion.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What happened when you tried to submit your app?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an iOS App submission can be done without owning a MacBook; it is **possible** to submit an iOS app using VMware to the App Store.

Your VM should run **Mac OS**, and an app should be done/built in **Xcode**.

What is important is that **Xcode will be required in order to upload a build to App Store Connect**. Then you may submit to the Apple Certification Team to review.

And ofc, To submit your app to the App Store, you need to enroll in Apple Developer Program ($99/year) that should be done prior to the steps described above.

Answer (score 0):

VMware doesn't matter as long as you are distributing your app via Xcode. Keep in mind the only way to distribute iOS application is to sign your application with Apple developer certificates with xcode and upload it via application uploader also you must have Apple developer account to generate distribution certificates.

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter applications, you can use a tool like Odevio (https://odevio.com/)

It allows you to configure and sign your app with Xcode as well as generating an .ipa file for testing on a physical device and publishing to the App store.